# Delete every column that contains a string in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big dataframe pandas on which I try to obtain the pearson coefficient. Some of the colums sometimes contain strings, I would like to delete all the columns of the dataframe that contain strings.
My code right now is not raising any errors but is not working.

```
def StringNoMore(dataframe):
    i=len(dataframe.index)-1
    print(i)
    while i > 0:
        for cell in dataframe.iloc[i]:
            dataframe=dataframe.loc[:, (dataframe != str).any(axis=0)]
        print(i)
        i-=1
    print("dataframe no string")
    return dataframe
```

Comment: Since any dataframe is not a string, `dataframe != str` is always `Tru`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do things would be to try to convert the column to some numeric type, e.g. `float` or `int`. If you can't convert each value in the column to numeric, then you know it contains `str`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 'abc', 'def', 3], 'B': [2, 2, 1, 4], 'C': ['a', 'a', 'b', 3]})

cols_to_remove = []

for col in df.columns:
    try:
        _ = df[col].astype(float)
    except ValueError:
        print('Couldn\'t covert %s to float' % col)
        cols_to_remove.append(col)
        pass

# keep only the columns in df that do not contain string
df = df[[col for col in df.columns if col not in cols_to_remove]]
```

Result:

```
>>> df
   B
0  2
1  2
2  1
3  4
```

Comment: For a *very* large df, you should make `cols_to_remove` a set, not a list.

Answer (score 2):

If your dataframe has only numbers, booleans, and strings, the following code works:

```
df = df[df.T[df.dtypes!=np.object].index]
```

Comment: I think I put my entire dataframe into bject at some point to avoid encoding problems, the @not_a_robot solution is working prety fast so i'm gonna stick with it, thx for the answer